# JAWS not reading the Control.AccessibleDescription property

Tags: winforms, accessibility, screen-readers, uiaccessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I'm using JAWS (2019) as a screen reader for a WinForms application.

When I set the `Control.AccessibleName` property - JAWS read it properly
but when I change the `Control.AccessibleDescription` property JAWS just doesn't read it.

I tried to use [INSERT] + [B] - It just read the screen again without the description.

Is anyone familiar with that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, It was easy one.

If you want JAWS to read the custom text you need to set the property:

```
ControlName.AccessibleRole = AccessibleRole.Application;
```

and then JAWS will read whatever you wrote in `ControlName.AccessibleDescription`

Comment: AccessibleRole is a clue to the screen reader as to what role the control plays in the application, so it can decide what to read. While in this case setting it to AccessibleRole.Application might work, it might not be the most correct thing, and lead to unexpected behaviour in other screen readers. You should check for the most appropriate [AccessibleRole enum value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.accessiblerole).